# Lambda function with loop and condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in Pandas DataFrame which I would like to process for all rows.

Example:

```
df_column:
    0     urewjf, abc, urewurwe
    1     fdsfs, kjf, oirpiewpoirew...
    2     ab, yryrewy, popof...
```

What I want to do with thouse values:

- add blank space in the beginning of the strings which have len<4 EXAMPLE: ' abc', ' ab'

I was trying to convert each row/Series into string and then run lambda function to apply it for each row:

```
list(map(lambda x: (x.rjust(5) for x in df.column if len(x) < 4), df.column))
```

It was not working.

Also, I have issues when I use .apply() because of the Series type, but apparantly my lambda function is not constructed correctly.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `urewjf, abc, urewurwe` is this a row of a column or a row of more columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a pandas vectorised string methods:

```py
df.<your_column_name> = df.<your_column_name>.str.rjust(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "TX_F1": [
        "urewjf",
        "fdsfs",
    ],
    "TX_F2": [
        "abc",
        "kjf"
    ]
})

df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).rjust(5))
```